# Javascript & JQuery - Append an input into multiple divs with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an add function to add a new one new input to all the columns with class name domestic.

Now I've created an code in JavaScript & Jquery, but it only adds it to the first 6, and does this 7 times.

Is it possible to do this? I've searched on numerous post's and haven't found any answer.

HTML

```
 <!-- START ONJECTIVES CONTAINER -->
    <div class="container" id="weighings">
      <!-- DOMESTIC NAME -->
      <div class="colum" id="columtext">
        <p>Domestic</p>
      </div>
       <!-- COLUM 4 DESCRIPTION -->
      <div class="colum discription domestic" id="regio">
        <p>Description</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 5 LOW -->
      <div class="colum domestic" id="regio">
        <p>Low</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 6 MEDIUM -->
      <div class="colum domestic" id="regio">
        <p>Medium</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 7 HIGH -->
      <div class="colum domestic last" id="regio">
        <p>High</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 8 LOW -->
      <div class="colum domestic" id="regio">
        <p>Low</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 9 MEDIUM -->
      <div class="colum domestic" id="regio">
        <p>Medium</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 10 HIGH -->
      <div class="colum domestic" id="regio">
        <p>High</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
     </div>
      <!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

SCSS

```
    #box{
             margin-top:5px;
             width:10px;
             height:10px;
             background:black;
            }

        .colum{
            display: block;
            width: 200px;
          text-align:center;
        }

    #regio{
      width:50px;
      margin-right:10px;
      input{
        width:50px;
      }
    }

  .row{
    width:100%;
    height:30%;
  }
```

Javascript & Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#newrow').click(function() {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('domestic');
    if (elements.length == 0) return false;

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id = 'box';
    input.type = 'text';
    input.oninput = 'calculate()';

      $(".domestic").each(function() {
          $(".domestic").append(input);
      })
  })
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/pNELXM?editors=0110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only creating one single element, and appending that element, so it ends up in the last place it was appended.

You have to create one element for each iteration of the loop, and you could use `append()` with a callback to iterate, instead of `each`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#newrow').click(function() {
        if ( $('.domestic').length === 0 ) return false;

        $(".domestic").append(function(i) {
            return $('<input />', {
                id   : 'box' + i,
                type : 'text',
                on   : {
                    input : calculate
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You're my hero T.T

Comment: @Notorious_Creed - you're welcome. Most likely you won't need the `if` condition, as it won't append anything if there are no matching elements.

Comment: I'm trying to create a button that removes the latest row i created. 

Do you have any advice what's the best way to do this?

Comment: They say, heroes don't wear capes. I'm indebted sir.

Answer (score 2):

Change your function on `.domestic` selector to

```
$(".domestic").each(function() {
 $(this).append(input);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

$('.domestic') is an array on its own; you don't need the .each function.  Just use

```
$(".domestic").append(input);
```

That should give you one new row with a new input appended to each div with class "domestic".